# Bind to attached property in ControlTemplate - Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, attached-properties

I have this style:

```
 <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                                        <StackPanel>
                           <Image Source="{Binding Path=local:AttachedProperties.Image}"  Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

The problem is that the binding does not work for a button:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Button" local:AttachedProperties.Image="../Images/UserChart.png" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which one isn't working? The Style or the attached property (or both)? If the attached property isn't working, you should post the code for it.

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it, this is a Silverlight issue.  More information at this post:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/102737/299184.aspx